# H2 db в SpringBoot не сохраняет данные

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Как настроить H2 в Spring Boot для постоянного хранения данных?

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.db.UserDao;
import com.example.demo.entities.User;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests  extends org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void createUser() {
        User user = new User("Petya");
        userDao.save(user);
        Assert.assertEquals("Petya", userDao.findByName("Petya").getName());  //true
    }
    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void getUser(){
        Assert.assertEquals("Petya", userDao.findByName("Petya").getName());   //no result exc
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
debug=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/mydb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Comment: пишут про `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47217202/2393786

Comment: по всей видимости у Вас данные сохраняются, но сносятся при повторном старте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В application.properties добавь

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```